# Prevent src from reload

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have an Iframe in a div and want to move it to another div, when i do that the iframe content is reloaded, it's possible prevent that happens? somehow prevent that iframe access the Internet.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <iframe id="iframe1" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kd9TlGDZGkI"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="wrapper2"></div>
```

```js
$('#iframe1').appendTo($('#wrapper2'));
```

Comment: _"prevent that iframe access the internet"_ sounds not logic to me...

Comment: I just want to prevent iframe load since I already have it on the site, but whenever I append it, is loaded again, "Prevent that iframe access the internet" was just an idea.